# Class to share data between two threads implemented as FIFO with std::queue

Tags: c++, thread-safety

I am trying to improve my code that involves a thread (`threadA`) handling some UDP communication and another thread (`threadB`) that works with the output of that communication.

My basic idea is to `.push()` new data into a `std::queue` within `threadA`.
`threadB` is looking for new data periodically - if it gets new data it processes it. Then `.pop` is called and the data is deleted.

Implementation:

1. `threadA` will call `addNewElement()` any time new UDP data arrives.
2. `threadB` will call `getNewestPtr()` to access the data.
3. when done with the data, `threadB` will call `doneWithNewest()`.

I am managing the access to the data (which comes in the form of `std::array`) through the use of `std::shared_ptr`. I know that the `shared_ptr` will manage the access to the pointer in a thread safe manner, but the underlying object is not going to be managed. *Here lies my problem* - in my implementation of the class, I am not sure where to put in memory locks, to ensure thread safety. My implementation already works, I have been testing it for a few days without problems, but I have the feeling I am doing something wrong, as I have not used any `std::mutex`. Anyway, here is my code:

**commbufferfifo.h**

```
#ifndef COMMBUFFERFIFO_H
#define COMMBUFFERFIFO_H

#include <queue>
#include <array>
#include <memory>

const size_t COMMLENGTH = 56;

/**
 * @brief The commbufferfifo class
 * @details used to safely share data between the comm thread and the visu thread
 */
class commbufferfifo
{
public:
    commbufferfifo();

    /**
     * @brief getNewestPtr  only accessed in visu thread
     * @return returns nullptr if fifo is empty!
     */
    std::shared_ptr<std::array<int16_t, COMMLENGTH>> getNewestPtr();///< @brief

    void doneWithNewest();///< @brief call when newest object can be deleted

    void addNewElement(const std::array<int16_t, COMMLENGTH> &commBuffer);  ///< @brief only accessed in comm thread

private:
    std::queue<std::shared_ptr<std::array<int16_t, COMMLENGTH>>> m_fifo;
};

#endif // COMMBUFFERFIFO_H
```

**commbufferfifo.cpp**

```
#include "commbufferfifo.h"

commbufferfifo::commbufferfifo()
{

}

std::shared_ptr<std::array<int16_t, COMMLENGTH> > commbufferfifo::getNewestPtr()
{
    if (m_fifo.empty())
        return nullptr;
    else
        return m_fifo.front();
}

void commbufferfifo::doneWithNewest()
{
    if (m_fifo.empty())
        return;
    else
        m_fifo.pop();
}

void commbufferfifo::addNewElement(const std::array<int16_t, COMMLENGTH> &commBuffer)
{
    m_fifo.push(std::make_shared<std::array<int16_t, COMMLENGTH>>(commBuffer));
}
```

some pseudo usage:
**main.cpp**

````
#include "includes/commbufferfifo.h"

#include <unistd.h>

void threadA(std::shared_ptr<commbufferfifo> myPointer){
    std::array<int16_t, COMMLENGTH> arr;
    for (int iteration = 0; iteration < 1000; iteration++){
        arr.at(0) = iteration;
        myPointer->addNewElement(arr);
        usleep(100);
    }
}

int main()
{
    auto sharedFifo = std::make_shared<commbufferfifo>();
    std::thread tA(&threadA, sharedFifo);

    usleep(10000);
    for(;;){
        if (sharedFifo->getNewestPtr() == nullptr)
            break;
        std::cout << "sharedFifo->getNewestPtr()->at(0) = " << sharedFifo->getNewestPtr()->at(0) << "\n";   //use data
        sharedFifo->doneWithNewest();                                                                       //data will be deleted
        usleep(1000);
    }


    tA.join();

    std::cout << "------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout << "done" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```
````

Answer (score 4):

This is more of a stackoverflow question but whatever.

1. There is no guarantee that `std::queue` is thread safe and methods `empty()/front()/push()` will properly interact in a multi-threaded environment. They most certainly cause data races. For this reason you need to use `std::mutex` to ensure that `std::queue` isn't accessed simultaneously from multiple threads ensuring that the data is read/written correctly.
2. What are you going to do when the queue is empty? What if you want to wait for next element? Will you put `sleep(10ms)` periodically? What if it isn't responsive enough and has too big of a lag? The proper method is to utilize `std::condition_variable` which has proper `wait/notify` methods.
3. It isn't worth to create a shared pointer to view some 100 bytes. You'd better transfer 100 bytes of data by copying it.
4. This isn't a C++ approach to transfer data by simply copying chunks of bytes. What you should do instead is to template your thread-safe queue over some class `T` so it moves `T`'s instances from sender to receiver in a safe way.